# difference between <>, =!, ==! in php

Tags: php, conditional-statements

Hi I am doing a conditional

```
if ($row['ConsignadaCaja'] === 'si' && $row['Estado'] ==! 'I') {
                $pago = 0;
}
```

It does not work as I want

So I try using

```
if ($row['ConsignadaCaja'] === 'si' && $row['Estado'] =! 'I') {
                $pago = 0;
}
```

But it does not work either

Finally I try this:

```
if ($row['ConsignadaCaja'] === 'si' && $row['Estado'] <> 'I') {
                $pago = 0;
}
```

It is works but do not why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`==!` is not the operator you are thinking of - You are mixing two operators here.

`==` [checks for equality](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), and `!` is a [logical not operation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php). So, you are actually performing one of these, thanks to [operator precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) putting `!` higher than the comparison or assignment operators:

```
if( $row['Estado'] = (!'I'))  // Assigns the inverted value of 'I' to $row['Estado']
if( $row['Estado'] == (!'I')) // Compares the inverted value of 'I' to $row['Estado']
```

Instead, you should be using `!=` or `!==`, depending on if you want type-coercion to occur.

Note that if you see that `<>` is working as expected, this is identical to the `!=` operator.